# Remove remote folder in ruby

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have a ruby script which runs on my local machine and it ftps a folder periodically from server. Now i want to remove the folder once i pull down the folder from ruby which is running on my local machine. Is it possible to do so?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I could see we can use sftp.remove("/path/to/file").wait to remove files and   sftp.rmdir("/path/to/directory").wait to remove folder.